# Scheme: when are expressions in let evaluated?

Tags: scheme, let

On page 66 of "The Seasoned Schemer" it says that `(let ...)` is an abbreviation for :

```
(let ((x1 a1) ... (xn an)) b ...) = ((lambda (x1 ... xn) b ...) a1 ... an)
```

Its used on for example on page 70:

```
(define depth*
  (lambda (l)
    (let ((a (add1 (depth* (car l))))
          (d (depth* (cdr l))))
      (cond
        ((null? l) 1)
        ((atom? (car l)) d)
        (else (cond
                ((> d a) d)
                (else a)))))))
```

But that above definition of `lambda` would suggest that `(add1 (depth* (car l))` and `(depth* (cdr l))` are evaluated and passed into the lambda represented by `(lambda (x1 ... xn) b ...)`. But this would mean that the list `l`, which could potentially be empty, would be passed to `car` and `cdr` before  the null check in `(null? l) 1)` is ever done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right in stating that `(car l)` and `(cdr l)` will get executed before testing if `l` is null, therefore raising an error if `l` is indeed `null`. Keep reading the book, in the following two pages this is explained, and a correct version of `depth*` is shown.

Answer (score 0):

The `let` syntactic keyword accepts the following form (ignore 'named-let'):

```
(define-syntax let
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((let ((identifier expression) ...) body ...)
     ;; ...)))
```

At the point where `let` is used each of `expression ...` is evaluated.  The expressions are evaluated in an unspecified order.

In your case, the expressions for `a` and `d` involving `depth*` **will** be evaluated before the body.  Thus, as you've concluded, `l` could be `'()` when `car` and `cdr` are invoked.